# verification check for login page not working

Tags: php, html, verification

I am working on a verification for my sign in using `php` for a side project. Right now I have one user which is the `admin` and the password is just `123`. If the user enter the wrong password or username, it will throw a message saying `Wrong Password` or `Wrong Username`. At the moment it doesn't do either and I am trying to figure out why. I will post the `html` and `php` down below.

Update: I have added the `method = post`. Not sure where to go from here.

```
<?php
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$passwd = $_POST['psw'];
$error = "";
$success ="";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($uname == 'admin'){
if($passwd == '123'){
  $error = "";
  $success = "Welcome Admin";
}
else{
  $error = " Wrong Password!!";
  $success = "";
   } 
}
 else{
   $error = " Wrong Username!";
  $success = "";
    }   
  }
 ?>





 <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <title>Hangman Home Page</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
 width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="home.css">
 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="header">
  <div class="a">Hangman</div>

 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
<!--column start here -->
<div class="hi">
<table id="leader">
  <tr>
    <th><img src="crown.gif"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leader Board</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1st. John : 4 guess</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2nd. Smith : 6 Guesses</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3rd. Tom : 7 Guesses</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4th. Allen : 8 Guesses</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
 <!-- form start here -->
 <br><br>
 <div class="b">Think You Can Beat #1 ?</div>

  <center><button 

 onclick=
"document.getElementById('id01').
 style.display='block'"
 style="width:auto;">Play Now!!! 
 </button></center>

 <div id="id01" class="modal">

<form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    <img src="hang1.gif" alt="logo" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <p class="error">
      <?php echo 'error'; ?>
    </p>
    <p class="success">
      <?php echo 'success'; ?>
    </p>
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you don't display either the error message or the success message. Here a code that should resolve your problem:

```
..............

<!-- in your form tag add attribute method="POST" -->

<!-- Your code -->
<!-- in your div class="container"> -->
<?php if($success) { ?>
    <p class="success"><?php echo $success; ?></p>
<?php } else if ($error) { ?>
<p class="error">
  <?php echo $error; ?>
</p>
```

```
<!-- Your code -->

Happy coding ;)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's some mistakes at your script. First, let's check your form:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
</form>
```

This code when filled and submitted, will result at those variables at your PHP script:

`$_GET["uname"], $_GET["psw"] and $_GET["remember"].`

You're trying to reach the data using `$_POST`, but this will happen only when you add the attribute *method="post"* at your *<form>* tag.

You can also reach the mixed `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays using `$_REQUEST`.

Another mistake it's the way you check if data has been submitted at the top of the code. There's no variable `$_POST["submit"]` (neither `$_GET["submit"]` or `$_REQUEST["submit"]`), because there's no variable with this name at the form, and you're probably thinking about submit button. To check if the form was submitted, the best way is to check if the username and password was not empty.

Also, you're echoing 'error' and 'success' at the form, and you're probably trying to echo the result of $error and $success.

Comment: Is there any way you can help start me out. I'm new to php and have been stuck at this for quite some time.

Comment: I think the best way you can learn basic PHP, it's from the official PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/index.php), and the comments are a great source of solution. You can also read the fast "Introduction Tutorial" at (http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php).

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing a string called success and error `<?php echo 'success'; ?>` what you should do is to echo the variables:

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
```

and:

```
<?php echo $success; ?>
```